# Dynamically Pick a Dynamic Range

Tags: excel, vba

I've spent several hours trying to come up with a clean solution to this, and I just don't seem to be able to.

Basically, I have several dynamic ranges that I have defined, and I want to select one based upon a condition. It seems so straightforward! The reason that I want to select this dynamic range is so that I can graph the range.

`Indirect` does not work.

`DIndirect` (A common VBA algorithm) does not work.

(Or I can't get them to)

`Choose` works! However, the maximum length of a dynamic range is very quickly reached, which means I'm forced into inane solutions like the following.

I define `dynamic_dynamic`

```
  =IF(A1<3,CHOOSE(A1,'WorksheetName'!dynamic_range_1, 'WorksheetName'!dynamic_range_2),'WorksheetName'!dynamic_dynamic_2)
```

Then I define `dynamic_dynamic_2`

```
  =IF(A1<5,CHOOSE(A1-2,'WorksheetName'!dynamic_range_3, 'WorksheetName'!dynamic_range_4),'WorksheetName'!dynamic_dynamic_3)
```

Then I define `dynamic_dynamic_3`

```
  =IF(A1<7,CHOOSE(A1-4,'WorksheetName'!dynamic_range_5, 'WorksheetName'!dynamic_range_6),'WorksheetName'!dynamic_dynamic_4)
```

.... And so on.

Really? I'm sure I'm being an idiot, but nothing else seems to work!

Comment: You sure indirect dont works? I will create a range of text representing the several ranges and use Indirect.

Comment: I've had no success with indirect. You'd have to do something like INDIRECT("'WorksheetName'!"&'WorksheetName'!$B$5), which fails.

Comment: I think your way to refer to the range it's not correct. INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1:A10")

Comment: That's a way to make INDIRECT work, but it won't help me here... I'm trying to work with dynamic ranges.

Comment: Seems like you should be able to run a for loop through all named ranges, and then use the chartwizard

Comment: Indirect does not work with *dynamic* named ranges, unfortunately.